# LyX left subscript in math formula

Tags: math-mode, lyx, subscripts

Does anyone know how to make a subscript on the left hand side in LyX in a formula?

Comment: Should be no different from making a subscript on the right side of a symbol, place the cursor to the left of the symbol and click the subscript-button.

Comment: The LaTeX code uses the `leftidx` package (eponymous command) or `mathtools` (`\prescript` command).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LaTeX, without using any additional package, you could use

```
${}_x F_x$
```

to write *<sub>x</sub>F<sub>x</sub>*. Using this as the baseline approach, inside a math formula, insert a subscript to "nothing", followed by the "middle symbol", followed by another subscript.

[image]

Comment: This is not very good, since if you have something before the first "_{x}", e.g. A _{x}F_{x}  then it would be typeset as if you have a subscript for A

Comment: @UrYa'ar: There are ways around that. Do you have any suggestions? Perhaps not using LyX? ;)

Comment: One way it to put a `{}` before. Another is to implement `\prescript` in a macro, I gave a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The `mathtools` package defines `\prescripts` which is supposed to give the right spacing for left super/sub-scripts.The syntax of the command is `\prescript{<sup>}{<sub>}{<arg>}`. To implement it in LyX one should define a macro as follows:
[image]
To get it, on the "TeX" box you write the following string (don't copy-paste as it won't work. While typing the script LyX will change e.g. `\{`  into the correct form of `{}`)

```
 \prescript\{\#1 \{\#2 \{\#3
```

and in order for it to preview nicely, write in the "LyX" box

```
^\#1 _\#2 \#3
```

of course you can skip either the sup or sub script argument, but you still need to have an empty '{}' for it, e.g

[image]

Note that if you get a compilation error you need to tell LyX to load `mathtools` via Document->Settings->Math options.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that I found to be easier than Werner's, and not requiring the extra packages and macros that Ur's solution needs:

Simply press `CTRL+SPACE` to make a half-space, which allows you to make the desired subscript:

[image]

Then delete the halfspace! 
Unlike Werner's solution, I never needed to click anything. My hands never had to leave the keyboard!